# Multi languages procedure style broken

Tags: android

In order to support german language i create a

> values-de

folder where i pasted all files from original

> values

folder with the appropriate changes to strings. App functionality remains ok but style is broken. Action bar doesn't show up app logo, text size is smaller and so on.
Any idea why this happens; Isn't app logo on action bar determined only by Manifest file; Is there anything else i must do that i forgot; Thanks in advance

Comment: German *language* requires `strings.xml` only. Obviously you changed other files in `values-de`.

Comment: I deleted every other file in values-de folder and now it works perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: Not only `strings.xml`, but also `arrays-xml`, if you use string arrays. All the rest, delete it from values-de

Comment: Awsome, I posted my comment as an answer, feel free to accept it then :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

German language requires `strings.xml` only.

Obviously you changed other files in `values-de`.

Clean those to solve ;)

Comment: Not only `strings.xml`, but also `arrays-xml`, if you use string arrays.

Comment: You're right. All that is not layout could cause problems, like `ids.xml` or `integers.xml` etc.

Comment: You mean `all that is not text`... ;) Not only it would be **harmful**, but it would also add an unnecessary **redundancy**.